# Rectangle coordinates bind to slider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do i bind the Y-coordinates to a slider and the width to a combobox so when u change the slider it looks like its crawling down the left side.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Grafik.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Y-Position des Objekts"/>
    <Slider Name="position" Minimum="0" Maximum="500" Canvas.Left="20" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="breite" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136">
        <ComboBoxItem >15</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem >30</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem >45</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem >60</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=position, Path=Value}"/>
    </Canvas>


</Grid>
```

Comment: There's an answer for you below, please respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

The binding to the slider's value works for me when I use your code.

You can bind directly to the combobox' value if you put real numbers in there. Otherwise you have to use appropriate converters.

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    >
    <ComboBox ...>
        <system:Double>15</system:Double>
        ...
    </ComboBox>
    <Rectangle ... Width={Binding SelectedItem ElementName=breite}/>
```

You might want to preselect a width with:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedIndex="0">
```